# How to restructure a mercurial repository with two main, parallel branches

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch

The history of my repository looks like:

```
A -- B -- C (branch "foo")
      \
       -- D (branch "bar")
```

The two branches are both "shipping" branches, and are essentially different frontends to a common backend.

All the code used to be in one branch, with the `foo` or `bar` features turned on or off by a compiler switch, but I branched to make it easier to work with each individually.

The problem is that the common "backend" files, by themselves, probably should be a separate branch - and I often want to *just* work on those common files. Because of the way I created these branches, the history is a bit screwed up: in branch `bar`'s past, it used to have features from `foo`.

Currently, I simply make changes on one branch and then use `hg transplant` to copy the same changes to the other branch.

Instead, I'd like to be able to make changes this way:

```
       __ C __ D'   (branch "foo")
      /      /
A -- B -- D         (branch "backend")
      \      \
       -- E -- D''  (branch "bar")
```

That is, work on the branch `backend`, and then in each of the shipping branches (`foo` and `bar`), I use `hg merge backend`.

What's the best way to go from my current situation to the one I'm describing? The only way I can think of is:

1. Remove all `foo` and `bar` features, and name that branch `backend`.
2. Delete the old `foo` and `bar` branches.
3. Manually add `foo` features to `backend` and name that branch `foo`, and likewise for `bar`.

Is there a better way?

Also, is this the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to split it into multiple repositories instead of several branches in one repository, as follows:

1. I closed the `bar` branch.
2. I cloned the original repository into a new repository `backend`.
3. I removed all of the `foo`-related code.
4. I pulled those changes into the main repository, and then immediately backed out of them (so the `foo` code remains). This became my `foo` repository.
5. I cloned the `backend` repository into a new repository `bar`.
6. I copied-and-pasted all of the files from the now-closed `bar` branch into the `bar` repository.

This kept my history for `foo`, and lost the history's continuity for `bar` (although all the history is still there, if I needed it); and now both `foo` and `bar` are clones, with modifications, of the `backend` repository, which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

How many changesets are there on branches `foo` and `bar`? Are the backend (transplanted) changesets separated from frontend changesets?

If the changesets are not many, and they are clean, then you might want to do this:

```
       C -- 1 -- 2 -- D -- 3   (branch "foo")
      /      
A -- B ----------- C" -- D"   (branch "backend")
      \      
       C' -- 4 ------ D' --- 5   (branch "bar")
```

(Here A, B, C, D are backend-related; 1, 2, 3 are foo-related; 4, 5 are bar-related.)

— i.e., create your brach `backend` based on the most recent common ancestor of `foo` and `bar`, then transplant all backend-related changesets there. From this point on, you'll be able to merge `backend` into either branch.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not this clean. There are lots of changesets on both branches. And the main issue, I think, is that the most recent common ancestor of `foo` and `bar` has *both* `foo` and `bar`-related stuff. I'd like a new branch that *just* has the `backend` stuff; but if I remove all of the `foo` and `bar` stuff from the new `backend` branch, then I wouldn't be able to do a straightforward merge into either branch.

Comment: @JesseBeder: Yeah, deleting can be problematic. You can delete everything but backend on `foo`, branch `backend` from there, then return on `foo` and backout the deletion. This way, next time you merge `backend` into `foo`, deletion will already be there. This does not take `bar` into account, though.

Comment: @JesseBeder: There are other approaches: 1) If the backend resides under a separate directory, you can probably use `hg convert` to filter out the history of this directory only, then `hg pull --force` into your original directory as the `backend` branch, or 2) if you don't care for history, just copy the backend's latest state to the new `backend` branch, and develop it from there. Which option suits you best?

Comment: No, unfortunately the backend isn't in its own directory. I guess it's looking like there aren't any great approaches, so I may just forget history and try to start over.

Comment: @JesseBeder: I'd still prefer my option (2) over your original plan, as (2) doesn't include deleting-and-recreating. Too bad the history is going to be lost.